# Pythonの文字列の先頭からn文字を削除する方法

Tags: python

```
test = "11111111isausa121ishauhsuayerstetsaosaopnhegywysaiosapsaasase"
```

というように文字列があったとして
先頭の10文字「11111111is」の部分を削除したい場合
どのように削除したら良いですか？

指定する文字列や、削除する文字数は変動するものとして、"先頭からn文字"を削除したいです。

Comment: 文字列の場合、スライス操作ができますので `test = test[10:]` などという書き方ができますが、これは削除ではなく置き換え(ポインタの付け替え)になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@metropolisさんのコメントのように、以下の記事を参照してスライスを使えば削除した結果を取得できます。
それを元の変数に代入すれば、文字列変数の「"先頭からn文字"を削除した」のと同等になります。

[3. 形式ばらない Python の紹介](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/introduction.html)
[3.1.2. 文字列型 (string)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

> 文字列は インデックス (添字) を指定して文字を取得できます。最初の文字のインデックスは 0 になります。文字を表す、専用のデータ型は用意されていません; 文字とは、単に長さが 1 の文字列です:
>
> インデックスに加え、スライス もサポートされています。インデックスは一文字づつ取得するのに使いますが、スライス は部分文字列を取得します:

[スライス Python3系の基礎文法（文字列）](https://qiita.com/Amtkxa/items/a03dabe050d8c648f098#%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9)

> ```
> >>> target = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMN'
>
> >>> # オフセット５から末尾まで
> >>> target[5:]
> 'FGHIJKLMN'
> ```

質問内容に適用すれば、以下のようになります。

```
test = "11111111isausa121ishauhsuayerstetsaosaopnhegywysaiosapsaasase"

delchars = 10 # 削除する文字数
test = test[delchars:] # 削除結果を元の変数に代入
print(test)
# 結果は ausa121ishauhsuayerstetsaosaopnhegywysaiosapsaasase
```